# Creating orange glow to indicate focused widget in Android

Tags: android, focus, widget, drawable

How to create the orange glow like the stock launcher has it when displaying the application list?

For example the highlighted aLogcat application below.

[image]

Is it built-in or do I need to calculate and create a new bitmap/drawable myself?

Answer (score 0):

yuku ,

you need to implement [custom components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) for that.This [post](http://www.anddev.org/tinytutcustom_button_backgrounds-better_imagebutton-t4298.html) at anddev may prove useful to you.

I believe you can dig out the rest!

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the source of the Google IO app

[iosched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/)

e.g. res/drawable/home_btn_sandbox.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/home_btn_sandbox_pressed"/>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/home_btn_sandbox_pressed"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/home_btn_sandbox_selected"/>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/home_btn_sandbox_default"/>
```

Comment: That is static. What I want is something like the picture I attached, where the shape of the focus glow is not from a resource, but seems like it depends on the shape of the icon. But -- thanks for the link! I didn't know they opensourced the iosched app!